# how to count number of occurances in hash values

Tags: perl

I have a below fix file and I want to find out how many orders are sent at same time. I am using tag 52 as the sending time.

Below is the file,

> 8=FIX.4.2|9=115|35=A|52=20080624-12:43:38.021|10=186|
>
> 8=FIX.4.2|52=20080624-12:43:38.066|10=111|
>
> 8=FIX.4.2|9=105|35=1|22=BOO|52=20080624-12:43:39.066|10=028|

If I want to count number how many same occurances of Tag 52 values were sent? How can I check?

So far, I have written below code but not giving me the frequency.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$f = '2.txt';
open (F,"<$f") or die "Can not open\n";
while (<F>)
{
        chomp $_;
        @data = split (/\|/,$_);
        foreach $data (@data)
        {
                if ( $data == 52){
                @data1 = split ( /=/,$data);
                for my $j (@data1)
                {
                        $hash{$j}++;
                } for my $j (keys %hash)
                        {
                                print "$j: ", $hash{j}, "\n";
                        }

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are there really blank lines between every pair of records in your data file?

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code corrected:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$f = '2.txt';
open (F,"<$f") or die "Can not open\n";
my %hash;
while (<F>) {
    chomp $_;
    @data = split (/\|/,$_);
    foreach $data (@data) {
        if ($data ~= /^52=(.*)/) {
            $hash{$1}++;
        }
    }
}
for my $j (keys %hash) {
    print "$j: ", $hash{j}, "\n";
}
```

Explanation:

1. `if ( $data == 52)` compares the whole field against value 52, not a substring of the field. Of course, you do not have such fields, and the test always fails. I replaces it with a regexp comparison.
2. The same regexp gives an opportunity to catch a timestamp immediately, without a need to split the field once more. It is done by `(.*)` in the regexp and `$1` in the following assignment.
3. It is hardly makes sense to output the hash for every line of input data (your code outputs it within the `foreach` loop). I moved it down. But maybe, outputting the current hash for every line is what you wanted, I do not know.

Comment: Thank you for your ans. But, when I run the code, it dose not give me the exact frequency of the each occurrence. Instead its printing only the hash value. I trying to get the frequency of each occurrence. Below is the o/p I am getting when I run the code.

20080624-12:43:38.021:

20080624-12:43:38.066:

20080624-12:43:39.066:

Comment: You can add a scalar counter that holds the total number of occurrences, increment it at the same time when `$hash{$1}`, and at the end, divide `$hash{$j}` by this counter.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Let me work on how to add counter.